# Inserting hyperlink to PDFs for each Polygon using QGIS?

Tags: polygon, hyperlink

I am currently using QGIS 2.18.16 and would like to know if you can you add a hyperlink to each line in the attribute table, I am wanting to hyperlink to PDF reports for each polygon.